# Why would one ActiveJob enqueue action be slower than another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm doing some performance tweaks to an app using stats gathered from [skylight.io](https://skylight.io), and one page that's a bit problematic is showing that a enqueing an ActiveJob job is taking an average of 21ms (the whole page takes 131ms on average, so this is 16% of the load time). The problematic action looks like this:

```
TrackVacancyPageViewJob.perform_later(vacancy.id) unless session[:session_id].present?
```

If I look at other similar enqueue actions, they're much quicker - more in the region of 2 - 5ms. Here's an example:

```
AuditExpressInterestEventJob.perform_later(
  datestamp: Time.zone.now.iso8601.to_s,
  vacancy_id: vacancy.id,
  school_urn: vacancy.school.urn,
  application_link: vacancy.application_link
)
```

Therefore, my question is, what could be causing this? They're all talking to the same redis instance, but seperate queues. Is the size of the queue the issue? Or is there something else I haven't considered?

Here are my jobs:

```
class TrackVacancyPageViewJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :page_view_collector

  def perform(vacancy_id)
    vacancy = Vacancy.find(vacancy_id)
    VacancyPageView.new(vacancy).track
  end
end
```

---

```
class AuditExpressInterestEventJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :audit_express_interest_event

  def perform(data)
    AuditData.create(category: :interest_expression, data: data)
  end
end
```

And my sidekiq.yml is here:

```
:queues:
  - [ mailers, 3 ]
  - [ queue_daily_alerts, 3 ]
  - [ email_daily_alerts, 4 ]
  - [ page_view_collector, 2 ]
  - [ performance_platform, 2 ]
  - [ google_indexing, 2]
  - [ import_school_data, 1 ]
  - [ update_vacancy_spreadsheet, 1 ]
  - [ audit_published_vacancy, 1 ]
  - [ audit_express_interest_event, 1 ]
  - [ audit_search_event, 1 ]
  - [ audit_feedback, 1 ]
  - [ audit_spreadsheet, 1 ]
update_vacancy_spreadsheet:
  :concurrency: 1
audit_published_vacancy:
  :concurrency: 1
audit_express_interest_event:
  :concurrency: 1
audit_search_event:
  :concurrency: 1
audit_feedback:
  :concurrency: 1
audit_spreadsheet:
  :concurrency: 1
audit_toc_acceptance_event:
  :concurrency: 1
mailers:
  :concurrency: 2
```

Comment: Mhm vague question vague guess: Maybe `TrackVacancyPageViewJob` has more requires or its more code to "boot up". Maybe you use `queue_as :low_priority`.

Where do you track the the vacancy page view? Maybe its external and it needs to build up the connection first?

Comment: Yeah, it is kinda vague I guess. I'll edit my question to include the jobs themselves. There doesn't seem too much to seperate them, other than the queues

Comment: `audit_published_vacancy` and `page_view_collector` have different weight. Have you tried using the same weight for both queues and if it makes a difference? Can't estimate if and how this makes a difference. Are both queues used at the same frequency or does `page_view_collector` have a multitude of jobs in comparison to `audit_published_vacancy`?

Comment: I'd say `page_view_collector` gets used a lot more than `audit_published_vacancy`